# How to get search a string with regex, and return empty when not found

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to search a string for example `Enter username:` and search for `:` and return anything before that. So that from the string above it would return `Enter username`, if the string was `Enter: username` or even `Enter : username` it would return `Enter` or `Enter_` **"_" being the space character.**

And finally if the string was `:Enter username` then it would return an *empty string*

```
String s1 = "Enter username:";
String s2 = "Enter: username";
String s3 = ":Enter username";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":");
String[] expected1 = p.split(s1); //Expected return: "Enter username"
String[] expected2 = p.split(s2); //Expected return: "Enter" 
String[] expected3 = p.split(s3); //Expected return: ""
//ignoring the print statement
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you just need split(":")

Comment: @KhalilM  Add a code example, and you've got a good up-vote-able answer there.

Comment: @KhalilM: he can use the [Pattern class's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) own split method: `Pattern#split(String input)` if he so desires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
package com.client;

import java.util.*;

public class UpvoteMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
                "Enter username:", 
                "Enter: username", 
                ":Enter username");

        for (String s : list) {
            String[] beforeColon = s.split(":"); 
            System.out.println(s + " -> '" + beforeColon[0] + "'");
        }

    }
}
```

Produces:

```
Enter username: -> 'Enter username'
Enter: username -> 'Enter'
:Enter username -> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the first (0th) element of the return array:

```
String s1 = "Enter username:";
String s2 = "Enter: username";
String s3 = ":Enter username";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":");

String[] expected1 = p.split(s1); //Expected return: "Enter username"
System.out.println(expected1[0]);

String[] expected2 = p.split(s2); //Expected return: "Enter" 
System.out.println(expected2[0]);

String[] expected3 = p.split(s3); //Expected return: ""    
System.out.println(expected3[0]);
```